# I need to get 3 letter month as 'Jan', 'Feb' using extract () function from date column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

date column's format : '2017-03-17'

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2017-03-17') FROM table;
```

It's giving me 3 instead of March.

Answer (score 2):

`extract()` returns a number.  You want a string, so you can use `to_char(<col>, 'Mon')`:

```
select to_char(now(), 'MON')
```

or for mixed case:

```
select to_char(now(), 'Mon')
```

Comment: @Dijkgraaf . . . I do.